# Crear un sistema de pila LIFO con descarte al estar lleno en Java

Tags: java, android, pilas

Quiero diseñar un sistema, estableciendo un método de almacén de datos, estilo pila, pero con la peculiaridad que cuando se llegue al máximo (3) el primer elemento de la pila sea eliminado, para así solo mantener los últimos valores.

**Diseño general:**

Mientras se pueda almacenar un dato que los ponga uno detrás de otro (1,2,3...)

```
1: A
2: B
3: C
```

Si la pila está llena y se quiere añadir un nuevo dato, el primero elemento se elimine y haga una rotación con los otros, para así el último dato introducido sea el último.

```
1: B
2: C
3: D
```

si se añade otro más (C,D,E) es decir solo se guarden los 3 últimos datos insertados.

El tipo de dato a guardar que sea de clase personalizada `TextDataStatus` 
El objeto de TextDataStatus

```
public class TextDataStatus {

    int action;
    String content;
    int start;
    int end;

    public TextDataStatus(int action, String content, int start, int end) {
        this.action = action;
        this.content = content;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public int getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(int action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public int getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(int start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public int getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(int end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TextDataStatus{" +
                "action=" + action +
                ", content='" + content + '\'' +
                ", start=" + start +
                ", end=" + end +
                '}';
    }
}
```

El método de extracción debe ser estilo `LIFO` (Last Input First Output) y que permite almacenar datos duplicados.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Aclaración:

Dices que quieres un [LIFO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_in,_first_out) (last in first out - *el último que entra es el primero que sale*), pero el ejemplo que proporcionas es un [FIFO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_in,_first_out) (first in first out - *el primero que entra es el primero que sale*), ya que estas eliminando la A que fué el primero en entrar.

Pero no te preocupes, sea cual sea tu caso (entiendo que FIFO) alguien ya se ocupó del tema y Java tiene clases para ello y, aunque no sean exactamente lo que tu necesitas, nos van a ahorrar la mayoría del trabajo.

---

## FIFO: [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

El objeto Queue es una implementación particular de LinkedList, puede hacer que el stack de objetos tenga su propio orden basándose en el `equals` y `hashCode` de los objetos que contenga, pero por defecto, es un stack FIFO tal y como podrás ver:

**EJEMPLO:**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

private final static String[] letras = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };

Queue<String> fifo = new LinkedList<String>();

for (String s : letras) {
    fifo.add(s);
}

System.out.println(fifo);

while (!fifo.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("La que se añadio mas recientemente es " + fifo.remove());
    System.out.println(fifo);
}
```

**SALIDA:**

```
[A, B, C, D, E]
La que se añadio mas recientemente es A
[B, C, D, E]
La que se añadio mas recientemente es B
[C, D, E]
La que se añadio mas recientemente es C
[D, E]
La que se añadio mas recientemente es D
[E]
La que se añadio mas recientemente es E
[]
```

---

## `LimitedFIFOList<E>`

A partir de ahí, con hacer una clase wrapper que proteja los metodos de añadir, podrás controlar lo del tamaño máximo y tener un getter del limite aparte de `size()`:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LimitedFIFOList<E> extends LinkedList<E> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int limite;

    public LimitedFIFOList(int limite) {
        this.limite = limite;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E o) {
        super.add(o);
        // si el tamaño fuera mayor eliminamos uno 
        while (size() > limite) { super.remove(); }
        return true;
    }

    public int getLimite() {
        return limite;
    }

    public void setLimite(int limite) {
        this.limite = limite;
    }    

}
```

Que usando el ejemplo anterior:

```
private static void FIFO() {
    LimitedFIFOList<TextDataStatus> fifo = new LimitedFIFOList<TextDataStatus>(3);

    for (TextDataStatus d : datos) {
        fifo.add(d);
        System.out.println(fifo.toString());
    }
}
```

**SALIDA:**

```
[TextDataStatus{action=1, content='A', start=1, end=6}
]
[TextDataStatus{action=1, content='A', start=1, end=6}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='B', start=2, end=7}
]
[TextDataStatus{action=1, content='A', start=1, end=6}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='B', start=2, end=7}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='C', start=3, end=8}
]
[TextDataStatus{action=1, content='B', start=2, end=7}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='C', start=3, end=8}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='D', start=4, end=9}
]
[TextDataStatus{action=1, content='C', start=3, end=8}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='D', start=4, end=9}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='E', start=5, end=10}
]
```

---

## LIFO Collection: [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

Ya que estamos y que la pregunta es un poco confusa, vamos a explicar también las clases LIFO que tiene Java y como ponerles un límite para tener la *parejíta* completa. Para ello, usaremos [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

> **The Stack class represents a last-in-first-out (LIFO) stack of objects**. It extends class Vector with five operations that allow a vector to be treated as a stack. The usual push and pop operations are provided, as well as a method to peek at the top item on the stack, a method to test for whether the stack is empty, and a method to search the stack for an item and discover how far it is from the top.

**EJEMPLO:**

```
import java.util.Stack;

private final static String[] letras = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };

Stack<String> st = new Stack<String>();

for (String s : letras) {
    st.add(s);
}

System.out.println(st.toString());  //     [A, B, C, D, E]
// cambiando el tamaño a menos de los objetos que contiene
// elimina los ultimos objetos añadidos
st.setSize(3);
System.out.println(st.toString());  //     [A, B, C]
// pop quita el que se haya añadido el ultimo
st.pop();
System.out.println(st.toString());  //    [A, B]
```

**SALIDA:**

```
[A, B, C, D, E]
[A, B, C]
[A, B]
```

---

## `LimitedLIFOList<E>`

Si tu caso fuera este, el wrapper seria muy parecido, pero con `Stack`

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class LimitedLIFOList<E> extends Stack<E> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int limite;

    public LimitedLIFOList(int limite) {
        this.limite = limite;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E o) {
        super.add(o);
        // si el tamaño fuera mayor eliminamos uno 
        while (size() > limite) { super.pop(); }
        return true;
    }

    public int getLimite() {
        return limite;
    }

    public void setLimite(int limite) {
        this.limite = limite;
    }
}
```

**EJEMPLO:**

```
private static void LIFO() {
    LimitedLIFOList<TextDataStatus> lifo = new LimitedLIFOList<TextDataStatus>(3);

    for (TextDataStatus d : datos) {
        lifo.add(d);
        System.out.println(lifo);

        if (lifo.size() == lifo.getLimite())
            System.out.println("quitamos > " + lifo.pop());
    }
}
```

**SALIDA:**

```
[TextDataStatus{action=1, content='A', start=1, end=6}
]
[TextDataStatus{action=1, content='A', start=1, end=6}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='B', start=2, end=7}
]
[TextDataStatus{action=1, content='A', start=1, end=6}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='B', start=2, end=7}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='C', start=3, end=8}
]
quitamos > TextDataStatus{action=1, content='C', start=3, end=8}

[TextDataStatus{action=1, content='A', start=1, end=6}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='B', start=2, end=7}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='D', start=4, end=9}
]
quitamos > TextDataStatus{action=1, content='D', start=4, end=9}

[TextDataStatus{action=1, content='A', start=1, end=6}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='B', start=2, end=7}
, TextDataStatus{action=1, content='E', start=5, end=10}
]
quitamos > TextDataStatus{action=1, content='E', start=5, end=10}
```

---

**NOTAS:**

- para conseguir tu objetivo debes implementar una LimitedFIFOList
- buscando información he visto que los chicos de Apache (como no... `^_^`) ya tiene una implementacion llamada [`CircularFIFOQueue`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html).
- ojo porque es posible cambiarles el tamaño, si quieres hacerla fija, sobreescribe el `setSize()` para que no haga nada.

  ```
  @Override
  public void setSize(int size) {
  }
  ```

---

Espero haberme explicado bien y aclaradas tus dudas, igualmente si tienes alguna duda, [sílbame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QO7KYyDSkXA) `:)`.

Comment: Estoy intentando usar LimitedFIFOList pero en Android veo que esa colección no existe.

Comment: No hombre, la he creado yo!! ;) Debes incluirla en tu proyecto, copy paste y llest!

Comment: ostras,me estoy dando cuenta que no he puesto el codigo de la `LimitedLIFOList`!! Cuando llegue a casa lo actualizo para que este la respuesta completa

Comment: Yo voy batellando, con la LimitedFIFOList que es la que me parece que es la indicada

Comment: si, por la muestra de datos yo he apostado por la FIFO (molaría que actualizaras el titulo y la pregunta si es así). Pero igualmente, me parece que completar la respuesta puede ayudar a futuros lectores y evitar preguntas sino duplicadas, muy similares.

Comment: Hay perdon me referia a LIFO ya que intento hacer un sistema de almacen de datos estilo undo, pero que solo se guarden los 3 últimos estados, y cuando se requiere extraer uno, se obtiene por la última modificación

Comment: no tengo ningun IDE a mano, pero viene a ser casi igual que la otra pero `public class LimitedLIFOList<E> extends Stack<E> {`, el metodo que tienes que sobreescribir (con el mismo código) es [`push(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#push(E)) es muy facil siguiendo el ejemplo de la otra

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta porque era un poco liosa. He mejorado las `LimitedXIFOList` con getters, setters para limite, cambiado el control del tamaño con un `while` para evitar problemas y mejorado los ejemplos usando tu clase `TextDataStatus`. Ahora creo que la respuesta esta completa :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solventada**
Gracias a la solución de @Jordi_Castilla he usado el método `LimitedLIFOList` siguiendo las indicaciones suyas he realizado lo siguiente:

```
public class LimitedLIFOList<E> extends Stack<E> {
    private int limite;

    public LimitedLIFOList(int limite) {
        this.limite = limite;
    }

    @Override
    public E push(E o) {
        super.push(o);
        if (size() > limite) { super.remove(0); }
        return o;
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
LimitedLIFOList<TextDataStatus> fifo2 = new LimitedLIFOList<>(3);

fifo2.push(new TextDataStatus(1,"A",0,0));
fifo2.push(new TextDataStatus(1,"B",0,0));
fifo2.push(new TextDataStatus(2,"C",0,0));
fifo2.push(new TextDataStatus(1,"D",0,0));
fifo2.push(new TextDataStatus(1,"E",0,0));
fifo2.push(new TextDataStatus(3,"F",3,1));
```

**Resultado:**

```
I/System.out: TextDataStatus{action=1, content='D', start=0, end=0}
I/System.out: TextDataStatus{action=1, content='E', start=0, end=0}
I/System.out: TextDataStatus{action=3, content='F', start=3, end=1}
```