# Como imprimir un formato lifo preguntando al usuario en java

Tags: java

necesito hacer un programa en el cual el usuario responde algunas preguntas que les da el cliente, al final del programa necesito mostrar en la consola el orden de las respuestas dadas por el usuario en formato lifo. A continuacion el codigo que tengo, ya hace las preguntas al usuario y esas cosas, lo que me falta por completar es como imprimir a la consola el formato lifo.

```
    int numeroemple = 0;
    String usuarios [] = new String[10];
    String ocupacion[] = new String [10];
    int pagoanual [] = new int [10];
    
    
     Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
     
     System.out.println("cuantos empleados hay?");
    numeroemple = scan.nextInt();
        
     
        for (int x = 0; x < numeroemple; x++)
        {
            
    System.out.println ("Escriba su nombre completo");

    usuarios[x] = scan.next();
    
    System.out.println ("Escriba su ocupacion");
    
    ocupacion [x] = scan.next();
    
    System.out.println ("Escriba su pago anual");
    
    pagoanual [x] = scan.nextInt();

    
        }
        
        int mayor = pagoanual[0];
        int menor = pagoanual[0];
        
        
        for (int x = 1; x < pagoanual.length; x++) {
            if (pagoanual[x] > mayor) {
                mayor = pagoanual[x];
        }
          for (int m = 0; m > pagoanual.length; m++) {
              if (pagoanual[m] < menor) {
                  menor = pagoanual[m];
              }
          }
        
        }
         
        for (int t = 0; t < numeroemple; t++)
        
        {
        System.out.println("El nombre es:" + usuarios[t] + ",su ocupacion es:" + " " 
        + ocupacion[t] +  ",el pago anual es:"+ " " + pagoanual[t]);
        }
    
        System.out.println ("El pago anual mayor es $" + mayor);
        System.out.println ("El pago anual menor es $" + menor);
```

Comment: Tienes claro qué implica LIFO y FIFO? Entonces añade la lógica que valide cómo quieres la salida y prodúcela de acuerdo a ese dato.

Comment: Responde [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15760/crear-un-sistema-de-pila-lifo-con-descarte-al-estar-lleno-en-java) tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, aprovecharía que Java es un lenguaje orientado a objetos y crearía un clase llamada respuesta.

```
public class Respuesta{
   private  String usuario;
   private  String ocupacion;
   private int pagoanual;
   public Respuesta(String usuario, String ocupacion, int pagoanual){
       this.usuario = usuario;
       this.ocupapacion = ocupacion;
       this.pagoanual = apagoanual;
   }

//getters y setters
}
```

Luego en vez de hacer tres arreglos distintos haces uno solo de respoestas:

```
Respuesta[] respuestas = new Respuesta[10];
```

en vez de...

```
usuarios[x] = scan.next();
```

ponés

```
String usuario =  scan.next();
String ocupacion =  scan.next();
int pagoanual =  scan.nextInt();

respuestas[x] = new Respuesta(usuario,ocupacion,pagoanual);
```

y así con el resto, ahora para tu pregunta, mostrar en orden LIFO...
LIFO significa "Last in first out", el Ultimo que ingresa es el primero en salir, quiere decir que si fuiste agregando en forma incremental al arreglo tenés que mostrarlo en forma decremental. Hay una estructura de datos que viene muy bien para este caso y se llama Pila, te invito que busques información al respecto.